# Inconsistent selector for querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

When using `:checked` selector in JavaScript, `document.querySelectorAll()`, I see there is an inconsistent behavior. When the `:checked` selector is used for checkbox or radio button it doesn't require space before the colon (:), but when this used for select options it requires a space before it. Why is it so?

Here are the examples:-

Checkbox: http://jsbin.com/fehonoho/1/edit?html,js,console

Select: http://jsbin.com/yasotuli/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked):

> For example, the `:checked` pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 `selected` and `checked` attributes as described in [Section 17.2.1 of HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1), but of course the user can toggle "off" such elements in which case the `:checked` pseudo-class would no longer apply.

The space preceding the `:checked` selector is nothing more than a descendant combinator, so the selector that you have is looking for descendants of a select that are `:checked`, rather than the select itself. These descendants are its option elements.

The `selected` attribute is found in option elements, not their parent select. In other words, a select can never match the `:checked` selector; only its options can. That's why you need a descendant (or child) combinator for it to work, unlike with checkboxes and radio buttons.

To make this clearer, it's highly recommended that you qualify the `:checked` selector with a type selector (a universal selector is implied otherwise):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name="aname"] option:checked')
```

Likewise with the attribute selector for the select element:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select[name="aname"] option:checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `:checked` element is the `<option>` not the `<select>` so you need either `option:checked` or `select :checked` where the latter has a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G7zTA/)

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the issue. The two selectors work as follows:

**`input[name="gender"]:checked`**

is a simple selector. It selects an `input` element with attribute `name=gender` and is `:checked`.

**`[name="aname"] :checked`**

are two simple selectors separated by the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#descendant-combinators). It selects all `:checked` elements that are children / grand children of an element with the attribute `[name=aname]`.

Note that `option` elements should be tested using `:selected`.